# change color of a colorCube from dynamic inputs in java3D

Tags: behavior, java-3d, cubes

I'm able to change the color of a cube at the beginning. but i want to constantly change it according to the changing value dynamically if I run the following code the color of the cube will be green and it will not be change again since this is run only one time. I was wondering if there's a way to change the colors few times using a class which extends behavior. Please let me know what is i'm missing. thanx in advance.

```
 protected BranchGroup getCube() {
        BranchGroup bg = new BranchGroup();
        BoundingSphere bounds = new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 10000.0);
   tg = new TransformGroup();
       t3D = new Transform3D();
   t3D.setTranslation(new Vector3d(-35.0f, -15.0f, 40.0f));
        tg.setTransform(t3D);
        cc = new ColorCube(3.0);
        SimpleBehavior4D3 b = new SimpleBehavior4D3(tg, gui);//changes position of the cube 
        b.setSchedulingBounds(bounds);
        b.setEnable(true);
        tg.addChild(b);

        QuadArray cube = new QuadArray(24, QuadArray.COORDINATES
                | QuadArray.COLOR_3);
        cube = (QuadArray) cc.getGeometry();
        cube.setColors(0, createGreen());
       if (b.liftCapacityStat().equals("full")) {
            cube.setColors(0, createRed());
        } else if (b.liftCapacityStat().equals("half")) {
            QuadArray cube1 = new QuadArray(24, QuadArray.COORDINATES
                    | QuadArray.COLOR_3);
            cube1 = (QuadArray) cc.getGeometry();
            cube1.setColors(0, createYellow());
        }

        tg.addChild(cc);
        bg.addChild(tg);
        bg.setUserData("Cube");
        return bg;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

(Note the snippet

```
final GeometryArray geometryArray = gi.getGeometryArray();
    {
      geometryArray.setCapability(GeometryArray.ALLOW_COLOR_READ);
      geometryArray.setCapability(GeometryArray.ALLOW_COLOR_WRITE);
    }
```

and the part where the Interpolator is defined

```
 final Interpolator colchange = new Interpolator() { ....
```

)

```
    package examples;

    import java.util.Enumeration;

    import javax.media.j3d.Alpha;
    import javax.media.j3d.AmbientLight;
    import javax.media.j3d.Appearance;
    import javax.media.j3d.BoundingSphere;
    import javax.media.j3d.Bounds;
    import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;
    import javax.media.j3d.DirectionalLight;
    import javax.media.j3d.Geometry;
    import javax.media.j3d.GeometryArray;
    import javax.media.j3d.IndexedTriangleArray;
    import javax.media.j3d.Interpolator;
    import javax.media.j3d.Node;
    import javax.media.j3d.PolygonAttributes;
    import javax.media.j3d.RotationInterpolator;
    import javax.media.j3d.Shape3D;
    import javax.media.j3d.Transform3D;
    import javax.media.j3d.TransformGroup;
    import javax.media.j3d.TriangleArray;
    import javax.media.j3d.View;
    import javax.media.j3d.ViewPlatform;
    import javax.vecmath.Color3f;
    import javax.vecmath.Point3d;
    import javax.vecmath.Vector3f;

    import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.GeometryInfo;
    import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.NormalGenerator;
    import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.MultiTransformGroup;
    import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;
    import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.ViewingPlatform;

    public class Example {

      public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new Example();
      }

      public Example() {
        final SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse();

        final BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();
        final TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup();
        final BoundingSphere bounds = new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 100.0);
        final Node blob = createMonster();

        { //to enable rotation
          tg.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
          tg.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_READ);
        }
        //    {
        //      tg.addChild(colchange);
        //    }
        // Create rotation to see all sides of the object
        final Transform3D btrans = new Transform3D();
        btrans.rotX(1);
        final Transform3D ztrans = new Transform3D();
        ztrans.rotZ(-1);
        btrans.mul(ztrans);
        final RotationInterpolator ri = createRotation(tg, bounds, btrans, 7000);
        tg.addChild(ri);
        {
          final Interpolator colchange = new Interpolator() {

            int colindex = 0;
            Color3f[] colors = new Color3f[] { new Color3f(0, 0, 0), new Color3f(1, 0, 0), new Color3f(0, 0, 1),

            };

            {
              final long milis = 9000;
              super.setAlpha(new Alpha(-1, Alpha.INCREASING_ENABLE, 0, 0, milis, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
              super.setSchedulingBounds(new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 100.0));
            }

            @Override
            public void processStimulus(final Enumeration criteria) {
              final Alpha alpha = getAlpha();
              if (alpha != null) {
                final float value = alpha.value();
                //   System.out.println("alpha=" + value);
                final Geometry geo = ((Shape3D) blob).getGeometry(0);

                colindex = (int) (value * colors.length);
                final Color3f color = colors[colindex];
                ((TriangleArray) geo).setColor(0, color);
                ((TriangleArray) geo).setColor(1, color);
                ((TriangleArray) geo).setColor(2, color);
              }
              wakeupOn(defaultWakeupCriterion);
            }

          };
          tg.addChild(colchange);

        }
        tg.addChild(blob);
        //
        group.addChild(tg);
        //
        addLight(group, new Color3f(1f, 1f, 0f), new Vector3f(4.0f, +7.0f, -12.0f));
        addLight(group, new Color3f(1f, 1f, 1f));
        //
        final ViewingPlatform viewingPlatform = universe.getViewingPlatform();
        final ViewPlatform view = viewingPlatform.getViewPlatform();
        view.setViewAttachPolicy(View.NOMINAL_SCREEN);
        viewingPlatform.setNominalViewingTransform();

        final MultiTransformGroup mtg = viewingPlatform.getMultiTransformGroup();
        final TransformGroup vtg = mtg.getTransformGroup(0);
        final Transform3D t1 = btrans;
        vtg.getTransform(t1);
        t1.setScale(2);
        vtg.setTransform(t1);
        group.compile();
        // add the group of objects to the Universe
        universe.addBranchGraph(group);

      }

      private Node createMonster() {
        final Shape3D child = createShape();
        final Appearance fillAppNode = new Appearance();
        final PolygonAttributes pAtt = new PolygonAttributes();
        // avoid trouble with clockwise faces
        pAtt.setCullFace(PolygonAttributes.CULL_NONE);
        pAtt.setBackFaceNormalFlip(true);
        fillAppNode.setPolygonAttributes(pAtt);
        child.setAppearance(fillAppNode);

        return child;
      }

      private Shape3D createShape() {
        final Point3d[] points = new Point3d[] {//
        new Point3d(-1, 1, 0), //
            new Point3d(1, 1, 0), //
            new Point3d(1, -1, 0), //
            new Point3d(-1, -1, 0), //
            new Point3d(0, 0, 1), //
        };
        final int[] idxs = new int[] {// the triangle faces
        0, 1, 2,//
            2, 3, 0,//
            1, 0, 4,//
            1, 2, 4,//
            2, 3, 4,//
            3, 0, 4 };
        final IndexedTriangleArray ita = new IndexedTriangleArray(points.length, GeometryArray.COORDINATES
            | GeometryArray.COLOR_3, idxs.length);
        ita.setCoordinates(0, points);
        ita.setCoordinateIndices(0, idxs);
        //per vertex colors really are per vertex reference
        //so each vertex can have a different color for each of its faces
        final Color3f[] colors = new Color3f[] {//
        new Color3f(1, 0, 1),//
            new Color3f(0, 1, 0),//
            new Color3f(0, 0, 1),//
            new Color3f(1, 1, 0),//
            new Color3f(1, 1, 1),//
        };
        ita.setColors(0, colors);
        ita.setColorIndices(0, idxs);
        ita.setColorIndices(0, new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 });
        //
        final GeometryInfo gi = new GeometryInfo(ita);
        //also generate normal vectors so that the surface can be light
        final NormalGenerator normalGenerator = new NormalGenerator();
        normalGenerator.generateNormals(gi);

        final GeometryArray geometryArray = gi.getGeometryArray();
        {
          geometryArray.setCapability(GeometryArray.ALLOW_COLOR_READ);
          geometryArray.setCapability(GeometryArray.ALLOW_COLOR_WRITE);
        }
        return new Shape3D(geometryArray);
      }

      private RotationInterpolator createRotation(final TransformGroup objScale, final Bounds bounds,
          final Transform3D btrans, final long milis) {
        final Alpha alpha = new Alpha(-1, Alpha.INCREASING_ENABLE, 0, 0, milis, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        final RotationInterpolator ri = new RotationInterpolator(alpha, objScale, btrans, 0.0f, (float) Math.PI * 2.0f);
        ri.setSchedulingBounds(bounds);
        return ri;
      }

      private void addLight(final BranchGroup group, final Color3f light1Color, final Vector3f ligthDirection) {
        {
          final BoundingSphere bounds = new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 100.0);
          final DirectionalLight light1 = new DirectionalLight(light1Color, ligthDirection);
          light1.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
          group.addChild(light1);
        }
      }

      private void addLight(final BranchGroup group, final Color3f light1Color) {
        {
          final BoundingSphere bounds = new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 100.0);
          final AmbientLight light1 = new AmbientLight(light1Color);
          light1.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
          group.addChild(light1);
        }
      }
    }
```